# Python - How to loop through a list while checking forward elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

Currently I am looking at a list of lists like this:
[[x, y, z], [x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2]...]

I would like to loop through and compare x1 to x2 and y1 to y2, if both are equal I'd like to add the value of z2 to z1 and make these into a new list.

`if x1 == x2 and y1 == y2:
    list.append(x1, y1, z1+z2)`

However I need it to be continuous so that if x3 and y3 are also equal to x2 and y2 then they will be added together just as before, and only added to the new list when the next value of x and y is no longer equal to the present ones.

Effectively, if a chain of 
`x1 == x2 == x3 == x4 and y1 == y2 == y3 == y4` evaluated to true then the new list should only contain one entry of [x, y, z1 + z2 + z3 + z4]

So far I've tried a recursive function within a for loop (and a list comprehension) however I'm running into all sorts of issues and I have no idea how people usually do this sort of thing.

Desired output:

`[[x1, y1, z1+z2+z3+z4], [x5, y5, z5], [x6, y6, z6+z7]...]`

My code so far (it's a bit messy. I got frustrated mid way through and tried changing a lot of it.):

```
list = [function(oldList, i) for i in range(len(oldList))]

def isNextElementEqual(list, index, totalTimeSpent = 0, count = 0):
    if list[index][2] == list[index + 1][2] and list[index][0] == list[index+1][0] and index+1 < len(list):
        totalTimeSpent += list[index][1]
        count += 1
        isNextElementEqual(list, index + 1, totalTimeSpent, count)
    elif count > 0:
        return [list[index][0], totalTimeSpent, list[index][2]]
```

Comment: can you show us what you've done so far? we can't just do work for you without proof of you trying

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the post, one moment.

Comment: What if y1=y2, but x1 != x2?

Comment: I don't need any data to be added to the new list if x1 != x2, so it isn't returned.

Comment: I posted what I've got so far, it's a little different to the simplified example I posted. I think I'm doing a lot wrong which is why I was asking for direction without my working so I can work in the right direction. I believe I may be approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import itertools

l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 7]]

print ([list(key) + [sum(group[-1] for group in groups)] for key, groups in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))])
```

Without List comprehension:

```
result = []
for key, groups in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
    group_res = list(key)
    group_res.append(sum(group[-1] for group in groups))
    result.append(group_res)
```

**Output**:

```
[[1, 2, 7], [1, 3, 18]]
```

---

#### Another example:

```
l = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 6], [2, 2, 10], [2, 2, 25], [3, 2, 14]]
[list(key) + [sum(group[-1] for group in groups)] for key, groups in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]
```

**Output**:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 6], [2, 2, 35], [3, 2, 14]]
```

#### Breakdown:

- In the innermost part of this one-liner, you see `itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))`. What this does is to group consecutive values it finds, by to the key function (`lambda x: (x[0], x[1])`). In this case, we group the values by the first two elements in each list.
- This function returns a tuple which consists of the `key` and the values that were matched consecutively for that key. This allows us to do `list(key) + [sum(group[-1] for group in groups)]` which takes the key and converts it to a list, then appends the sum of their last elements to the list.

Comment: I'm not super experienced so this solution looks a little confusing but thank you! I didn't know about itertools and it worked!

Comment: @Weresdrim sorry about that. List comprehensions are sweet, but can easily become a nightmare to the inexperienced eye. I have updated my post with a loop version, so you can better understand what is going on

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile :)

Answer (score 1):

This requires you to check through each value in the list y for each x, which will become computationally expensive. But it works.

```
x = [[ 0,  1,  2],
     [ 1,  1,  6],
     [ 2,  2, 10],
     [ 2,  2, 25],
     [ 3,  2, 14]]

y = [x[0]]
for val in x[1:]:
    for ix, i in enumerate(y):
        if val[0] == i[0] and val[1] == i[1]:
            i[2] += val[2]
            break
    else: y.append(val)

print(y)
```

Comment: The output for that is:
`[[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 12], [2, 2, 45], [3, 2, 28]]`

The output I'd like would be:
`[[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 6], [2, 2, 35], [3, 2, 14]]`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that.

Comment: `for val in x[1:]:` is the same as `for val in x[1:len(x)]:`